# VIM - E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command

Tags: vim

When I issue

```
:A
```

I get:

```
E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command
```

I know I can see the commands with:

```
:command
```

Which produces this list:

```
    Name        Args       Address   Complete  Definition
    ALEDetail   0                                  :call ale#cursor#ShowCursorDetail()
    ALEDisable  0                                  :call ale#toggle#Disable()
    ALEDisableBuffer 0                                  :call ale#toggle#DisableBuffer(bufnr(''))
    ALEEnable   0                                  :call ale#toggle#Enable()
    ALEEnableBuffer 0                                  :call ale#toggle#EnableBuffer(bufnr(''))
    ALEFirst    0                                  :call ale#loclist_jumping#JumpToIndex(0)
    ALEFix      0                                  :call ale#fix#Fix()
    ALEFixSuggest 0                                  :call ale#fix#registry#Suggest(&filetype)
    ALEGoToDefinition 0                                  :call ale#definition#GoTo({})
    ALEGoToDefinitionInTab 0                                  :call ale#definition#GoTo({'open_in_tab': 1})
    ALEInfo     0                                  :call ale#debugging#Info()
    ALEInfoToClipboard 0                                  :call ale#debugging#InfoToClipboard()
    ALELast     0                                  :call ale#loclist_jumping#JumpToIndex(-1)
    ALELint     0                                  :call ale#Queue(0, 'lint_file')
    ALENext     0                                  :call ale#loclist_jumping#Jump('after', 0)
    ALENextWrap 0                                  :call ale#loclist_jumping#Jump('after', 1)
    ALEPrevious 0                                  :call ale#loclist_jumping#Jump('before', 0)
    ALEPreviousWrap 0                                  :call ale#loclist_jumping#Jump('before', 1)
    ALEReset    0                                  :call ale#toggle#Reset()
    ALEResetBuffer 0                                  :call ale#toggle#ResetBuffer(bufnr(''))
    ALEToggle   0                                  :call ale#toggle#Toggle()
    ALEToggleBuffer 0                                  :call ale#toggle#ToggleBuffer(bufnr(''))
!   AddTabularPattern +                                  call AddTabularPattern(<q-args>, <bang>0)
!   AddTabularPipeline +                                  call AddTabularPipeline(<q-args>, <bang>0)
!   Ag          *                                  call fzf#vim#ag(<q-args>, <bang>0)
    AirlineRefresh 0                                  call s:airline_refresh()
    AirlineTheme ?                    customlist    call <SNR>26_airline_theme(<f-args>)
    AirlineToggle 0                                  call s:airline_toggle()
    AirlineToggleWhitespace 0                                  call airline#extensions#whitespace#toggle()
    Annotate    *                                  call CallDeprecatedCommand('BookmarkAnnotate', [<q-args>, 0])
!   BCommits    0                                  call fzf#vim#buffer_commits(<bang>0)
!   BLines      *                                  call fzf#vim#buffer_lines(<q-args>, <bang>0)
!   BOnly       ?                    buffer        :call BufOnly('<args>', '<bang>')
!   BTags       *                                  call fzf#vim#buffer_tags(<q-args>, <bang>0)
!   Bonly       ?                    buffer        :call BufOnly('<args>', '<bang>')
    BookmarkAnnotate *                                  call BookmarkAnnotate(<q-args>, 0)
    BookmarkClear 0                                  call BookmarkClear()
    BookmarkClearAll 0                                  call BookmarkClearAll(0)
    BookmarkLoad 1                                  call BookmarkLoad(<f-args>, 0, 0)
    BookmarkMoveDown ?                                  call s:move_relative(<q-args>, 1)
    BookmarkMoveToLine ?                                  call s:move_absolute(<q-args>)
    BookmarkMoveUp ?                                  call s:move_relative(<q-args>, -1)
    BookmarkNext 0                                  call BookmarkNext()
    BookmarkPrev 0                                  call BookmarkPrev()
    BookmarkSave 1                                  call BookmarkSave(<f-args>, 0)
    BookmarkShowAll 0                                  call BookmarkShowAll()
    BookmarkToggle 0                                  call BookmarkToggle()
!   BufOnly     ?                    buffer        :call BufOnly('<args>', '<bang>')
!   Buffers     ?                    buffer        call fzf#vim#buffers(<q-args>, <bang>0)
!   Bufonly     ?                    buffer        :call BufOnly('<args>', '<bang>')
    CheckHealth *                    customlist    call health#check([<f-args>])
    ClearAllBookmarks 0                                  call CallDeprecatedCommand('BookmarkClearAll', [0])
    ClearBookmarks 0                                  call CallDeprecatedCommand('BookmarkClear', [])
```

How to debug further or what is the issue?

Comment: Given you have at least 15 commands beginning with "A" what exactly are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `:A` vim will try to execute a command that starts with `A`, because you have more than one command that starts with `A` it can't decide which one to execute, hence the ambiguity.

In my case I used to type `:Ex` to execute `Explore`, then I installed a plugin that added the commands `ExDocs` and `ExDef`, so now to launch `Explore` I need to type `:Exp`.